# images are not displayed in preview panel , when i add images as folder inside inside drawable

Tags: android, image, android-drawable

I want to add images as separate folders inside the drawable folder, so how can I do it?
  for example, 100 images should be separated into four folders which each folder should contain 25 images.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this drawable folder must be fat. **instead put them outside of folders but in drawable folder** and start name for each group with the group name like this:

```
group1_image1.xml
group1_image2.xml
group1_image3.xml

group2_image4.xml
group2_image5.xml
```